# Access Form Design - subforms going crazy

Tags: ms-access

im fighting with access 2007 right now.
i cant make the form designer to cooperate with me, especialy when using subforms.
the just do what they want.

does anybody know about a good guide how to layout beautiful forms (that include subforms) with access 2007. what a mess...

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Access Developer's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0782140114) is a great resource for all things Access.

[When I first used Access (some time ago), this book showed me how to layout a form with a subform, itself containing another subform. I can't recommended this book enough.]

Comment: Note however that this book won't tell you about the new features in A2007.

Comment: ...and the new features in regard to form layouts are pretty extensive in A2007. There's at least one whole new view, the split form.

Comment: +1 because it doesn't seem right to have an accepted answer with negative votes.